# Get Order Summary Details Using Session?

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento Checkout page i want to get the Cart Details Like

> Product name,
>   Price,
>   Quantity,
>   product Image.

Using Session . . 
I dont know how to get the session Details..
Kindly Help Me out here. .

Comment: in which step.after order place or before order

Comment: After order place

Comment: on checkout success page or else?

Comment: Beside checkout page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your order from checkout session .Then using order id you can get orders item details by load of sales  models.

```
 $session=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout();
$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId();
$orderId= $session->getLastOrderId();
// If checkout onepage singleton not work then use checkout session
if(is_null($orderId)){
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
}

        if ($orderId) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            if ($order->getId()) {
                 $items =$order->getAllVisibleItems();

                foreach ($items as $item)
                {
                    $item->getName(); // product name 
                    $item->getPrice();
                    $item->getSku();    
                    $item->getProductId();
                    $item->getQtyOrdered(); 
                    // load product model for gettting images
                    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                    if($product->getId()):
                    echo $product->getSmallImageUrl();
                    endif;
                }

             }
         }
```

Comment: but if we apply this code only one product will appering in display. . if we add another one product in cart , the product price only updated in grand total not the name, quantity etc. . what to do??